# How to setup JMS bridge to ActiveMQ on Weblogic 11g

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic, messaging, weblogic11g

I'm novice guy in JCA and JMS parts of Java EE stack, and now I'm struggling with **JMS bridge configuration** between two JMS providers (ActiveMQ 5.9.1 -> Weblogic 11g 10.3.5), and I need some help to understand all the moving parts and required configuration elements.

What I've done already:

1. JMS server configured on Weblogic 11g node
2. Configured **Foreign Server** - AMQ connection factory, and source queue objects bound to the local JNDI (OK: conn. factory and queue objects visible in server jndi tree)
3. Create **JMS Bridge** with default props (OK - I think)
4. Created the Bridge Destination for **target destination (Weblogic)** with default configuration - where possible (OK: Resource Adapter deployed)
5. Created the Bridge Destination for **source destination (AMQ)** - JNDI properties, default props where possible (FAIL - Cannot connect to the source destination)

And there is the question:

By default there are two resource adapters (XA, non-XA), do I need install the AMQ specific resource adapter?

I've assumed that yes, so I've downloaded **rar** file on Weblogic machine, then tried to install with Weblogic Console (Deployment -> Install), but.. another trouble - no way to achive Running state in Deployments view. I've read that all jars from rar need to be placed in Weblogic CLASSPATH, so I've copied them to Weblogic lib directory. But, with no success so far.

So, what I did wrong, where is the gap or an error in this configuration?

I have studied the Oracle documentation, but I feel still didn't get the complete understanding of the bridge config :((

Any explanatory replies very appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, problem solved. I've used wrong JNDI names of connection factory and queue - local names defined in Foreign Server configuration instead of names on remove JMS server.

Actually, no additional configuration like Foreign Server, or Resource Adapter is needed here.

Comment: You may need to start another question. Also try to mark this one as answered

Comment: Topic continued in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24676937/javax-crypto-badpaddingexception-when-connecting-to-tibco-ems-with-ssl